# Android 11 Stops recording audio in foreground service , if app goes background or killed

Tags: audio-recording, mediarecorder, android-11, foreground-service

I have stared a foreground service that make a call on server, but I want to record a audio as well that a user is sneaked, I am using MediaRecorder class to record audio in foreground service but it works only until application foreground when application killed or goes background its stop recording, I Have followed @Google Developers guide regarding Android11 changes but its not worked

> ```
>  <service ...
>         android:foregroundServiceType="location|camera|microphone" />
> ```
>
> startForeground(notification,FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE)

but nothing worked using Accessibility Service as well, Looking forward for your comments